# text field receiving optional('value") instead of "value "

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to pass a text that is correct api put in swift he arrives with the message of "optional". this is my code:

```
let accountValues:NSArray = account!.accountNumber.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "-"))
self.accountTextField.text = accountValues.objectAtIndex(0) as? String
self.accountDigitTextField.text = accountValues.objectAtIndex(1) as? String
```

Comment: so is it an issue with double quotes ?

Comment: double quotes? I believe they do not interfere!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When retrieving the value, use ! after the value. The downcast should force unwrap any optionals. Anything set as? can be force unwrapped by using !.
For example,

```
let intString = 7 as? String

print(intString!)
```

This should print "7", rather than Optional("7")

Answer (score 0):

You're using Optional Value "As? String". So, it will return an Optional('value').

Try this:

```
let accountValues:NSArray = account!.accountNumber.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "-"))
self.accountTextField.text = "\(accountValues.objectAtIndex(0))"
self.accountDigitTextField.text = "\(accountValues.objectAtIndex(1))"
```

Comment: this return a warning and the problem continue

Comment: also did not work, I believe the componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet this already returning value to this optional message

Answer (score 0):

please replace these lines :

```
 self.accountTextField.text = accountValues.objectAtIndex(0) as? String
 self.accountDigitTextField.text = accountValues.objectAtIndex(1) as? String
```

by :

```
self.accountTextField.text = (accountValues.objectAtIndex(0) as! String)
self.accountDigitTextField.text = (accountValues.objectAtIndex(1) as! String)
```

Comment: Can you declare accountNumber in account class as non optional ? var accountNumber : String! = ""

Comment: It seems that Optional("value") come from the values that you use for populate accountNumber property.